# Eclipse RCP swt browser on RHEL 7

Tags: eclipse, browser, swt, rcp, rhel7

Open browser in eclipse RCP doesn’t work under RHEL7

Specifications:
SWT plugin version: org.eclipse.swt_3.8.0.v3833.jar
Eclipse version:3.8.2
OS:RHEL7

A.  The approach followed to resolve the Browser issue on RHEL7

1. Installing libwebkit2gtk:

As suggested, the following commands were used to install libwebkit2gtk-
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install libwebkit2gtk

But the issue was not resolved. Stack trace is as follows-
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]

2. Using other native Mozilla-based browsers:

In the system analyzer code, in BrowserView.java class, change to SWT.MOZILLA while creating the browser.

Set the environment variable MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to the native browser's installation folder.
MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/bin/Mozilla
Set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

In eclipse, add this line in Run configuration->Arguments->VM arguments
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

But the issue was not resolved. Stack trace is as follows-
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]

3. Installing xulrunner-

Downloaded and install XULRUNNER from https://eclipse.org/atf/old/downloads/base_files/manualXulrunner_section.php

In eclipse, add this line in Run configuration->Arguments-VM arguments
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/xulrunner1.8.0.4/xulrunner/xulrunner

But the issue was not resolved. Stack trace is as follows-
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005

Comment: I'm having the same issue with CentOS 6.7. It works with the app running inside eclipse, but not as a standalone app. And it works with a standalone app on Ubuntu. Also I don't see package libwebkit2gtk. I have webkitgtk and webkitgtk-devel installed.

Comment: In a CentOS 7.1 system, I was able to get the Browser working with style SWT.WEBKIT by installing the yum package webkitgtk3. It still does not work in CentOS 6.7, where webkitgtk3 is not available.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after installing yum package webkitgtk3.